# What is the energy associated with the degrees of freedom of a nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, degrees-of-freedom

I am following R.M. Martin in his book *Electronic Structure: Basic Theory and Practical Methods*. On page 11 he explains that we discriminate between properties of matter due to the electric ground state, and excited states. He writes

> The reason [for the division of properties of matter] is that materials are composed of nuclei bound together by electrons. Since typical energy scales for electrons are much greater than those associated with the degrees of freedom of the more massive nuclei, the lowest energy ground state of the electrons determines the structure and low-energy motions of the nuclei.

I thought the degrees of freedom were the coordinates used to describe motion? I did not think they could have an intrinsic value, as they can be defined in any number of ways, but energy does not depend on how we measure the nuclei. Can you explain what Dr Martin tries to get across?

Comment: Not an expert, so I'm not gonna try to give an answer by myself, but maybe this is helpful: http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~mds21/thesis/node20.html

Comment: Energy is not Lorentz-invariant. It is one component of a Lorentz four-vector, and thus transforms under Lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes, the energy of the nuclear motion can be anything, but for the configurations being described here, you're not interested in the full arbitrary range of values a given variable can hold ─ you're interested in the range of values that it actually does hold in practice. This is why the text emphasizes that this is the *typical* range for the variables involved.

The nuclear-motion dynamics that Martin is describing here is that of rotational and vibrational motion in molecules, and that of phonons in condensed-matter systems. Here the typical energy scale is determined by the separation between eigenstates, and it is in the range of millielectronvolts or smaller ─ much smaller than the multi-electronvolt transitions involved in electronic dynamics.

The real name for the principle that Martin is describing here is the [Born-Oppenheimer approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation), and this is the name to use to search if you want to read more deeply into the topic.